# Объединить ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Имеется много ajax на разных страницах. Можно ли сделать так чтобы постоянно не писать ajax для каждой формы, а сделать что-то универсальное. Может есть готовые решения? Я вот набросал свой вариант, правильна ли такая реализация?

```
$(".ajax").submit(function(e){

        var $form = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr("action"),
            type: $form.attr("method"),
            data: $form.serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function() {
                var $btnsubmit = $form.find(".btn-submit");

                if( $btnsubmit.attr("data-load") ) {
                    $btnsubmit.addClass( $btnsubmit.attr("data-load") );
                    $btnsubmit.attr("disabled", true);
                }
            }

        }).done(function(data){
            console.log( data );

            $.each(data, function(i) {
                if(data[i].action == 'reload')
                {
                    location.reload();
                }

                if(data[i].action == 'redirect')
                {
                    window.location.replace(data[i].link);
                }

                if(data[i].action == 'alert')
                {
                    alert(data[i].text);
                }

                if(data[i].action == 'modal')
                {
                    $(data[i].id).modal({
                        clickClose: false
                    });

                    $(data[i].id + " .ok").click(function(){
                        if(data[i].modalOk == 'reload')
                        {
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    });
                }

                if(data[i].action == 'addclass')
                {
                    $(data[i].element).addClass(data[i].class);
                }

                if(data[i].action == 'removeclass')
                {
                    $(data[i].element).removeClass(data[i].class);
                }

                if(data[i].action == 'changetext')
                {
                    $(data[i].element).text(data[i].text)
                }

                if(data[i].action == 'changehtml')
                {
                    $(data[i].element).html(data[i].html)
                }

                if(data[i].action == 'changeval')
                {
                    $(data[i].element).val(data[i].val);
                }

                if(data[i].action == 'changevalselect')
                {
                    $(data[i].element).val(data[i].val).change();
                }

                if(data[i].action == 'show')
                {
                    $(data[i].element).show();
                }

                if(data[i].action == 'hide')
                {
                    $(data[i].element).hide();
                }

                if(data[i].action == 'attr')
                {
                    $(data[i].element).attr(data[i].name, data[i].attr);
                }
            });

        }).fail(function(data){
            console.log( data );
        }).always(function(data){
            var $btnsubmit = $form.find(".btn-submit");

            if( $btnsubmit.attr("data-load") ) {
                $btnsubmit.removeClass( $btnsubmit.attr("data-load") );
                $btnsubmit.attr("disabled", false);
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Суть такая что каждая форму, у которой есть класс ajax, отправляется методом ajax. В ответ приходит json с массивом действий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, написать одну функцию, которая бы объединяла все запросы, которые будут встречаться в проекте - это не очень правильное решение. Как минимум из-за того, что Вам прийдется загружать эту функцию на любой странице, даже если Вам необходим будет лишь 1 запрос.

Для себя я написал 1 функцию, которая в коллбэке возвращает мне результат запроса.

```
function sendAjaxRequest(search, obj, callback){
    var data = JSON.stringify(obj);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", search, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        xhr.send(data);
        console.log("Запрос ушел")
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (xhr.readyState !=4) return;
            if(xhr.status == 200) {
                return callback(xhr.responseText);
            }
        };
```

};

пример использования:

```
sendAjaxRequest("/cart", {id:1}, function(result){
    console.log(result)
})
```

Конечно, эта функция не лишена недостатков (не кроссбраузерная, например) - но для понимания - пойдет.
У участника `SO` @Air, видел кроссбраузерную. Поищите у него или в ответах или в вопросах.

Comment: То есть вы всё равно предлагаете около каждой формы писать свой ajax запрос?

Comment: Я делаю так. Ведь каждый запрос требует подготовки, раз, отправки, два, и обработки ответа, три. Если в Вашем проекте подготовка и обработка заключается только в 1-й строчке, типа `alert(data[i].text);`, то возможно Вам будет удобнее сделать так как Вы спрашиваете. Но все равно,Вам прийдется инициализировать отправку запроса возле каждой формы. Да и `Ajax` не только для форм

Comment: Где-то прочитал, что каждая функция должна делать что-то одно, но хорошо.